# Is it possible to combine several (form) search fields into one with checkboxes and/or dropdown?

Tags: html, forms, button, search, checkbox

I am using my own starting page for my browsers. This page is used by myself only (and some friends and family). Which contains news, weather, links and such.

Also this page includes several search fields, like Google, Usenet, forumsearch (on a favourite website) and a subtitles search field. Ofcourse each search field uses different queries for different sites.

Now as I am redoing the starting page, I am wondering if it's possible to create just one search field and use checkboxes to select the page I want to search. By default it should check Google, but if I select the checkbox for subtitles it would use the search field to search for subtitles (on the appropiate website).

If this isn't possible, would it be possible with a dropdown or something similar? Or maybe a different approach or solution to this?

When both are not possible or takes a massive amount of coding / tweaking, I will refer to using multiple search fields as I did before.

I took a screenshot of how the search fields are currently (on the old design) to give you an impression.

[image]

Reason for switching to checkboxes / dropdown field is, is that I can add more searches without making the page look messy.

While typing this and looking at things, once more, maybe a better solution would be to just create several buttons and use only one search field? Still might be a little tacky, but that could actually work. What do you think?

And like I said; if it takes to much coding or tweaking just tell so. I am just wondering if there is a different approach to this.

---

**Update**

Though Yoda's solution is great. It's getting a bit confusing with several search fields (if I have to remember every string needed to do a search).

Wouldn't it be possible to use checkmarks or even buttons to select which search is being used?

For example we have one search field but have several (simple) buttons to select which search is going to be used? By default it should always use Google search imho.

Or is it possible to add those strings to a button (toggle) instead? By default it will always select Google, otherwise it will use the search if the button is toggled for newsgroups, forum search, etc.?

Comment: how about using a string, so you could do `g:nick cage` for google or `u:ghost rider` for usenet. Then you just parse the string and send it to the appropriate place, all you need then is to put a reference list on the page, you have huge scope to expand it also.

Comment: Thank you for this idea. Will give it a go :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in my comment, you can implement a search system which uses a single text input, it parses the user input for a service identifier denoted by a letter followed by a colon.

> i.e. "g:" will map to the google service.

The rest of the input will then be sent to a service class which deals with making the specific requests.

This is very similar to the bang notation used by duckduck go who essentially implement the very functionality you are creating.

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fLf60Lg2/2/) demonstrating the logic which is implemented using technology introduced in the [ES6 Standard for javascript](http://es6-features.org/#Constants).

You can see browser support for various features in this or any other [ES6 compatibility table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/)

```js
class Search {
    constructor(options) {
        this.searchInputClass = options.searchInputClass;
        this.searchButtonClass = options.searchButtonClass;
        this.serviceMap = options.serviceMap;
        this.validator = options.validator;
        this.defaultService = options.defaultService;
        this.textParser = options.textParser;
        this.cacheElements();
    }

    cacheElements() {
        this.searchInputElement = document.querySelector(this.searchInputClass);
        this.searchButtonElement = document.querySelector(this.searchButtonClass);
    }

    bindEvents() {
        this.searchButtonElement.addEventListener('click', this.onSearchButtonClick.bind(this));
    }

    onSearchButtonClick() {
        this.currentInput = this.getTextInput();
        const isValid = this.validator.validateInput(this.currentInput);
        if (isValid) {
            const serviceId = this.textParser.extractServiceIdentifer(this.currentInput);
            const matchedService = this.matchIdentifierToService(serviceId);
            this.invokeService(matchedService, this.textParser.extractQuery(this.currentInput));
        } else {
            this.invokeService(this.defaultService, this.currentInput);
        }
    }

    getTextInput() {
        return this.searchInputElement.value;
    }

    matchIdentifierToService(serviceId) {
        return this.serviceMap[serviceId] || this.defaultService;
    }

    invokeService(service, query) {
        service.call(query);
    }
}

class TextParser {
    extractServiceIdentifer(inputString) {
        return inputString.substring(0, 1);
    }

    extractQuery(inputString) {
        return inputString.substring(2).trim();
    }
}

class Validator {
    constructor(options) {
        this.textParser = options.textParser;
    }

    validateInput(inputString) {
        return this.validateServiceTarget(inputString);
    }

    validateServiceTarget(input) {
        const test = /[a-z]/;
        const colonIndex = input.indexOf(':');
        const hasColon = colonIndex === 1;
        const inputCharacter = this.textParser.extractServiceIdentifer(input);
        const isValidCharacter = inputCharacter.match(test);
        return hasColon && isValidCharacter !== null;
    }
}

class SearchFactory {
    constructor(options) {
        this.Search = options.Search;
        this.Validator = options.Validator;
        this.TextParser = options.TextParser;
    }

    build(options) {
        const textParser = new this.TextParser();
        const inputValidator = new this.Validator({
            textParser,
        });
        const search = new this.Search({
            validator: inputValidator,
            textParser,
            defaultService: options.defaultService,
            searchInputClass: options.searchInputClass,
            searchButtonClass: options.searchButtonClass,
            serviceMap: options.serviceMap,
        });

        return search;
    }
}

class GoogleService {
    constructor() {
        this.name = 'Google';
    }

    call(query) {
        console.log(this.name, query);
    }
}

class UsenetService {
    constructor() {
        this.name = 'Usenet';
    }

    call(query) {
        console.log(this.name, query);
    }
}

const searchFactory = new SearchFactory({
    Search,
    Validator,
    TextParser,
});

const search = searchFactory.build({
    searchInputClass: '.js-search-input',
    searchButtonClass: '.js-search-button',
    defaultService: new GoogleService(),
    serviceMap: {
        g: new GoogleService(),
        u: new UsenetService(),
    },
});

search.bindEvents();
```

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

.page-search-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.search-input {
  width: 500px;
}

.search-button {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-search-container">
  <input type="text" class="search-input js-search-input">
  <input type="button" class="js-search-button search-button" value="search">
  <h3>Available Services:</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>g: - google</li>
    <li>u: - usenet</li>
  </ul>
  <p>
    i.e. "g: nick cage" will result in a google search for "nick cage"
  </p>
  <p>
    Check the console logs for output.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I updated / edited my question, can you please take a look when you have time? TY.

Comment: Sure. Out of interest, how did you get on with ES6 syntax?

Comment: Thank you kindly! Well I started with the ES6 and it worked, however with several seaches it's get "difficult" to remember what string to use. :)

Comment: Yeah fair enough, well hope it helps. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

it is possible by recording the responses of the check box. Say for example if you set check box as default, you must have a name or id for it so while checking for query you can formulate a if-else ladder or switch condition to finalize the query and perform the corresponding search